# Check conflict after git pull in script

Tags: bash, git, git-subtree, git-merge-conflict

I've the following script in a git repository, that allows me to add a subtree and performing push and pull in automatic way.

```
#!/bin/bash

# The script will update subtrees of the repository. Subtrees are stored in
# thirdparty folder.
#
# Since in a fresh clone subtrees are missing, the script at first will check if
# corresponding remotes are present. If they are missing then remotes will be
# created. Then, it starts the synchronization. Subtree repositories will be
# pulled, synchronized, with the current conflict resolution, and then pushed.

# Remotes
SUBTREELIB_REMOTE=name-of-subtree-remote
SUBTREELIB_URL=git@remote-git-address.git
SUBTREELIB_BRANCH=branch-that-must-be-checked-out
SUBTREELIB_PATH=path/where/subtree/is/stored

###############################################################################
# FUNCTIONS SECTION                                                           #
###############################################################################

# Exit if the tree is not clean.
RequireCleanWorkingTree () {
    # Update the index
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    err=0

    # Disallow unstaged changes in the working tree
    if ! git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules --
    then
        echo >&2 "cannot $1: you have unstaged changes."
        git diff-files --name-status -r --ignore-submodules -- >&2
        err=1
    fi

    # Disallow uncommitted changes in the index
    if ! git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD --ignore-submodules --
    then
        echo >&2 "cannot $1: your index contains uncommitted changes."
        git diff-index --cached --name-status -r --ignore-submodules HEAD -- >&2
        err=1
    fi

    if [ $err = 1 ]
    then
        echo >&2 "You need to commit or stash changes before updating subtrees."
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Function for syncronyzing a remote
#
# It needs 4 arguments:
#
# - The name of the remote that will be used in the repository
# - The url of the remote where it can be fetched
# - The branch of the remote that must be syncronized
# - The path where it must be stored in the repository.
function SyncronizeRemote {
  # Check if remote is present and add it if missing.
  echo "Testing if $1 is present"
  git ls-remote --exit-code $1
    if test $? != 0; then
      echo "Adding missing remote $1"
      git remote add -f $1 $2
      echo "Adding subtree for $1"
      git subtree add --prefix $4 $1 master --squash
  fi

  # Fetching remotes
  echo "Fetching remotes for $1"
  git fetch $1 $3

  # Pull remotes
  echo "Pulling remotes for $1"
  git subtree pull --prefix $4 $1 $3 --squash

  # Push remotes
echo "Updating remotes for $1"
git subtree push --prefix=$4 $1 $3
}

###############################################################################
# EXECUTION SECTION                                                           #
###############################################################################

# Ask ssh key password only once.
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/*_rsa

RequireCleanWorkingTree
SyncronizeRemote $SUBTREEIB_REMOTE $SUBTRELIB_URL $SUBTREELIB_BRANCH $SUBTREELIB_PATH
```

It works, but it has the problem than if I've a merge conflict after the pull, it doesn't stop and it does the push. For example if I have a conflic the output is:

```
Agent pid 1825
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa)
Testing if name-of-subtree-remote is present
a38faec39bf7f5515f570eb2835dfa80555e9be1        HEAD
8aa678cdca32b2fe6d91edb8d0097a6e0b6eeea9        refs/heads/develop
a38faec39bf7f5515f570eb2835dfa80555e9be1        refs/heads/master
Fetching remotes for name-of-subtree-remote
remote: Enumerating objects: 19, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), 3.58 KiB | 85.00 KiB/s, done.
From 192.168.100.236:loginlib
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
   00d5585..8aa678c  develop    -> name-of-subtree-remote/develop
Pulling remotes for name-of-subtree-remote
From 192.168.100.236:name-of-subtree-remote
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in path/where/subtree/is/stored/src/File1.hpp
Auto-merging path/where/subtree/is/stored/src/File1.hpp
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in path/where/subtree/is/stored/src/File2.hpp
Auto-merging path/where/subtree/is/stored/src/File2.hpp
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in path/where/subtree/is/stored/src/File3.hpp
Auto-merging path/where/subtree/is/stored/src/File3.hpp
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
Updating remotes for name-of-subtree-remote
git push using:  name-of-subtree-remotedevelop
219/475 (212) [13]
```

I want that the script stops if I've a merge conflict with the pull, so I can solve the merge conflict and re-run the script in order to avoid problems.

How can I modify the script in order to check if there's a merge conflict and exit if there is?

Comment: `if ! the_command; then exit; fi`. (or `set -e`, but for `set -e` you will have to rewrite parts of your script)

Comment: Side note: if you source the `git-sh-setup` script (run `git --exec-path` and look in that directory for the shell libraries), you'll find a bunch of functions for checking for clean work-trees and the like.

Comment: @KamilCuk ok I'll check it thanks.

Comment: I would wonder if this is possible to automatically resolve conflicts and commit...